# What update was released to Windows XP SP3 this week that would take 15 minutes to install?

Tags: windows-update, shutdown, freeze

I've been very happy with my Windows XP SP3 box, but right now it is shutting down, and has been for 15 minutes, pausing while "Installing update 1 of 1..", this then changes to "Do not turn off or unplug your computer; it will turn off automatically." and then back.

Normally I hate to interfere with this kind of thing, but right now it seems like something is  wrong. In fact, the screen just blanked into power-save mode, but it keeps going after I hit a key.

What possible update is out there this week [Oct 19-23 2009] (I just did an update last week) and is it supposed to take a very long time?

Comment: An update that disables and deletes XP completely now that Windows 7 is out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a hotfix to Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 2.0. These are parts of the ["huge patch" from last week](http://gcn.com/Articles/2009/10/09/Microsoft-Patch-Tuesday.aspx?Page=1). So my timeframe was off by a week. These kinds of things can be searched for at the [security bulletins pages](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/current.aspx).

But my real issue was that the patch was so huge it wouldn't install in the little free space I had left (600MB).

Now I really have a reason to slap in the 5 500GB disks I bought last year and never setup because I actually wanted them to run on a solaris machine as a raid-z pool. That ended up not happening, yet.

Comment: Any particular reason your hard drive is spilling over? System performance is usually best while you're still below the 75 % full mark. Having only 600 MiB free sounds not very fun to use.

Comment: It's only 600MB on the C partition, the D, E, and F partitions have 1, 2 and 50GB free respectively, and I found that it wasn't killing me.